# Delete File History With Client Object Model (Sharepoint Foundation 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

I'm using the Client Object Model to interface my application to SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

This application generates some versions of the same file... it's possible to see all the versions in the file version history...

The problem is that I have to delete the old versions of the file, not necessarily all of the versions...

Is it possible to do this? How can I do this?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var fileName = '/myfile.txt';
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileName).get_versions().deleteAll();
c.executeQueryAsync();​
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)  Feel free to consider accepting the answer if you think it gave you the appropriate amount of assistance.